# How to get user (authenticated) ID in order to save data submitted by an anonymous user?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to let an anonymous user submit data through a modelform which is on a user's profile page and have that data saved (once submitted) to the user whose profile it was on. The approach I was thinking was to take in a 'pk' parameter to my view function (from my url pattern) and bind it to the user id of the page they are on and save it. Is there a way to get the user id of the profile page the anonymous user is submitting the form on? Or is there a better approach to doing this altogether? *I just need to bind the data submitted by the anonymous user to the authenticated user.*

My model uses a foreign key to the authenticated User. I have one model which is a model for ideas (called Ideas) and they all belong to one user. And as new profiles get created, each user will have their own set of ideas and so on. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Get something unique on behalf of user (email for example) while submitting the form, then use email as username

Comment: Maybe I am over thinking it, but is there a way to just have the modelform data save to the user who's profile they are visiting?